# How could I access local variables or call local functions in lua scripts from C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, lua

If I define a "local" function, as such:

local function Dispatch(archive)
  coroutine.resume(yielder)
end

...and I want to call this function from C++, I do not think I can use the
lua_getglobal() call:

```
m_pThreadState = lua_newthread(m_MasterLuaState);
//Load/define the above "Dispatch" routine local to this thread.
luaL_loadbuffer(m_pThreadState, m_ScriptBody, strlen(m_ScriptBody),"Console");
lua_getglobal(m_pThreadState, "Dispatch"); //UH-OH!! PROBLEM HERE!!
lua_pcall(m_pThreadState, 1, 0, 0);
```

So how do I specify/push the local function "Dispatch" in preperation for
the call?  Again, I assume I cannot use the lua_getglobal() call, because
the "Dispatch" function is defined as "local" to the m_pThreadState.  What
do I do?

Comment: assign them to variables in the global table, or to a table accessible from the global table.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But in case it is, you still shouldn't do it unless you like to confuse people just for the sake of being confuse people. (Because *why would you do that* instead of just making it global?)

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want the function to be local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access local variables from C (aside from debug API, but I don't think that's what you want).

Local variables (and functions, since they're variables) are what they are - local, ie accessible only from within their surrounding scope.

So you're left with two options:

- create a global variable
- call a C function from Lua and pass the local function as a
  parameter. Then you will have the function on the stack and will be
  able to call it from C (from within the C function). Now there is little point in doing that, I was just merely pointing at the way it could be done.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think the second option is suitable but maybe it should edit the lua script. I want to find the local table from lua and manipulate it with C API. And finally I use the pattern-matching method to extract the table and write it into a new lua file to make it global. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @user3483507 this all looks terribly complicated. Perhaps you could describe your actual problem rather than your attempted solution? Perhaps there is a better approach to you problem, as what you're describing seems suboptimal at best.